# Understanding Ruby on Heroku 'config vars' example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

In [Getting Started with Ruby on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#define-config-vars), the following example is given as a use of config vars:

```
<h1>Getting Started with Ruby</h1>

<p>
  Welcome!
</p>

<% for i in 0..(ENV['TIMES'] ? ENV['TIMES'].to_i : 2) do %>
  <p>Hello World #<%= i %>!</p>
<% end %>
```

This method is supposed to run for the number of the TIMES environmental variable, but it doesn't make sense according to my understanding.

I understand the ruby syntax

`truthy_or_falsey_value ? evaluates_if_truthy : evaluates_if_falsey`

but here we have something that looks similar in syntax but can't be the same thing semantically.  Would someone who understands please explain what's going on?  Many thanks!

Comment: Why can't that be the same? It's exactly what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a ternary operator and you're right that these two are equivalent:

```
ENV['TIMES'] ? ENV['TIMES'].to_i : 2
truthy_or_falsey_value ? evaluates_if_truthy : evaluates_if_falsey
```

So what's happening is that the ternary operator is used to populate the last argument of a Range:

If `ENV['TIMES'] is nil then the for loop will be:

```
for i in 0..2
```

If `ENV['TIMES']` is set to 50, the the for loop will be:

```
for i in 0..50
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Heroku but what I understand from that statement is this:

First you have a for loop which will loop from 0 to a specific value. Then you have a conditional statement which, if true, will return `ENV['TIMES'].to_i` (the `.to_i` converts the return value of `ENV['TIMES']` to an integer), otherwise it will result in 2. Now if you combine both the conditional and the for loop you can figure out what is going on.
If ENV['TIMES'] evaluates to true then the range of the for loop will be from 0 to the value returned from `ENV['TIMES'].to_i`, otherwise the range will be from 0 to 2. So the final result will be "Hello World" being repeated `i` times, dependent on whether or not `ENV['TIMES']` exists. I am new to Ruby as well and not very familiar with the syntax but hey, that is what I make of it.